# Proof of non-uniformity of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Show that it is not true that for every error $\frac{1}{m}$ there exists $n$ such that $|\sum_{k=1}^n r^k - \frac{r}{(1-r)}|<\frac{1}{m}$ for all $r$ in $0<r<1$.

My take on it:

$$
\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty r^k\right|<\frac{1}{m} \Rightarrow r^{n+1} < \frac{1}{m} \Rightarrow \log{r^{n+1}} < \log{\frac{1}{m}} \Rightarrow (n+1)\log{r} < \log{\frac{1}{m}}\Rightarrow\\
\Rightarrow -(n+1)\log{\frac{1}{r}} < -\log{m} \Rightarrow (n+1)\log{\frac{1}{r}} > \log{m} \Rightarrow \frac{\log{m}}{\log{\frac{1}{r}}}<(n+1)
$$

Here $m$ is fixed and for any $n$ we could select such $r$ close to $1$ that the last inequality isn't valid.

Could you please verify the proof and pinpoint any mistakes that I made?
Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: The mistake is that is not written in sentences. Replace each of the semi-colons with "$\implies$".... But the logic is correct. You could also shorten it as follows: If $m>1$ then $\sum_{k>n}r^k<1/m\implies r^n<1/m$ $\implies r<(1/m)^{1/n} <1$  so the main inequality is invalid for $ r\in [(1/m)^{1/n},1).$

Comment: You take a confusing approach. Isn't it clear that the limit of the left side is $\infty$ as $r\to 1^-?$